# Reading audio file from movie clip 'avi' files

Tags: matlab, audio, video, image-processing, signal-processing

I want to do speaker as well as face recognition in a movie clip, the characters voice and face as well.I am unable to read audio file in .avi file in MATLAB 7.10 R2010a. can anyone help me?

Comment: mmreader and aviread....

Comment: Use [`vision.VideoFileReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereaderclass.html) System object.

Comment: there is no computer vision toolbox in MATLAB 7.10a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/access-to-audio-part-of-the-video-file)):

```
 file = 'filename.avi'
 file1 = 'audiofile.wav'
 hmfr=video.MultimediaFileReader(file,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
 hmfw = video.MultimediaFileWriter(file1,'AudioInputPort',true,'VideoInputPort',false,'FileFormat','WAV');
 while ~isDone(hmfr)
      audioFrame = step(hmfr);
      step(hmfw,audioFrame);
 end
 close(hmfw);
 close(hmfr);
 audio_samples = wavread(file1);
```

Comment: m trying the same: `AudioVideo=video.MultimediaFileReader(filname,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',true);

while ~isDone(AudioVideo)
[video,Audioframe]= step(AudioVideo);
end
close(AudioVideo)` sir, can you jus explain me how i can access eacd sample and frame simultaneously

Comment: when i am using above code i am getting empty matrix in Audioframe

Comment: @sneh123 Double check whether `audiofile.wav` is saved sucessfully or not.

Comment: u didnt get ma problem i don't have separate voice and video file, i want to process on a movie clip having both audio and video i.e, _.avi_ file

Comment: @sneh123 I know that. The above code will first read the audio from the video and then save it to disk. Then you can read it from disk.